# The most idiomatic preposition in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: prepositions

What is the most idiomatic preposition in the following sentence

> She might do that ------ different intentions.

I mean to say, in doing so, she might have different intentions: intention to help, intention to show off, intention to benefit ...

Which preposition is most idiomatic for the black: with, by, through, ...?

Comment: *She might do that .... **for any number of reasons*** is an idiomatic phrase that would fit your scenario.   **different intentions** is not the proper phrase.   You can ask *Who can say what her intentions might be? She could have done that for any number of reasons.*

Comment: "She might do that *with* different intentions."